# Formatear una matriz y pasarla a un DataTable mediante un WebServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Les comento estoy tratando de utilizar *DataTables* realizando un *WebServices* a otro servidor, el cual me devuelve una matriz en *Javascript* con los siguientes valores:

```
[
    ["2017-05-25 23:10:00","0","100","17.2"],
    ["2017-05-25 23:20:00","0","100","17.2"],
    ["2017-05-25 23:30:00","0","100","17.2"],
    ["2017-05-25 23:40:00","0","100","17.1"],
    ["2017-05-25 23:50:00","0","100","17.1"],
    ["2017-05-26 00:00:00","0","100","17"]
]
```

Código:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js">
</script>
<head>
  <title>tablas</title>
<script>

$('#example').DataTable( {
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": {
       "url": "servidor remoto",
       "type": "POST",

   },

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>dato1</th>
            <th>dato2</th>
            <th>dato3</th>
            <th>dato4</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
</body>
```

Necesitaría formatear con *jQuery* dichos valores y presentarlos en la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, tienes que definir que columnas estas recibiendo desde el ajax, esto sirve para identificar cuantos parámetros esperas que se muestren en la tabla.

```
columns:[
  {data: Dato1},
  {data: Dato2},
  {data: Dato3},
  {data: Dato4},
]
```

Si tu json o tu matriz que recibes  solo contiene esos 4 datos en el orden que esperas no hay necesidad de usar en el ajax `dataFilter`, pero si necesitas ordenar es recomendado usarlo, por lo tanto la inicialización del datatables quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": {
       "url": "servidor remoto",
       "type": "POST",
       "dataFilter": function(data){
          //primero recomiendo revisar que es lo que hay en data
          //console.log(data)
          var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );//string --> json
          json.recordsTotal = json.total;//obteniendo el total de registros
          json.recordsFiltered = json.total;//total de registros filtrados
          json.data = json.list;//informacion que va en la tabla

          return JSON.stringify( json ); // return JSON string
       }
   },
   columns:[
     {data: Dato1},
     {data: Dato2},
     {data: Dato3},
     {data: Dato4},
   ]
});
```

> **Nota:**
>   Debes tener en cuenta que tienes que obtener un json como lo indica en la documentacion https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que debajo del thead ponas el tbody ,  ejm:

```
<tbody id="tableBody">
</tbody>
```

en el success del ajax

```
success: function(data){
   for(var i = 0 ; i<data.length;i++){
   $("#tableBody").append("<tr>")  
    for(var j = 0 ; j<4 ;j++)
    {
      $("#tableBody").append("<td>"+data[i][j]+"</td>")
    }
  $("#tableBody").append("</tr>")
  }
 }
```